# Trying to insert another DOCX file contents into a ContentControl using Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to take a byte[] of a docx file and I want to insert the contents of that docx file into a ContentControl I got from a different docx file. We do something similar elsewhere where I put in some text that has to have some special formatting and use new XWPFDocument() in the new XWPFParagraph lone. So I thought since the byte[] is already a docx, that I could just pass it as a XWPFDocument. But I am getting blank in the Content Control.

What am I doing wrong in this code, that there is nothing showing in the content control after this code runs? And if this content control is within a "sentence" and we want whatever is inserted into the ContentControl to stay in that same line, not putting in a carriage return, wouldn't putting a WXPFParagraph into it force it carriage return? Should we be doing that as a Run instead? Thanks

```
    void setContentControlClause(SDTContentControl contentControl) {
        //file is actually retrieved in code that would be here, but don't need to post that

        XWPFDocument doc = null
        try {
            doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(new ByteArrayInputStream(file.fileData)))
        } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage(), e)
        } catch (InvalidOperationException invalidFile) {
            invalidFile.printStackTrace()
        }
  
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = new XWPFParagraph(CTP.Factory.newInstance(), doc)
        contentControl.setContent(paragraph)
    }
```

Comment: `XWPFParagraph paragraph = new XWPFParagraph(CTP.Factory.newInstance(), doc)` creates a new **empty** paragraph in `XWPFDocument doc`. Then you are inserting that **empty** paragraph into the content control. That's why it is empty too.

Comment: I doubt it is possible to put the content of a whole Word document into a content control. You should think about storing the content somewhere else. As text in a text file for example. Inserting text into a content control is possible. Or selecting only one `XWPFParagraph` out of the document to put this into the content control. I have already shown how to do this.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter, you are always of great help. Unfortunately, I can't make the specifications/requirements of the client, so I have just try and do what they ask. ;) These other documents won't have much text in them anyway as they are just "clauses", so short snippets of text that can be re-used in many different contracts. I was able to get it to work last night and will post my solution right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with that appears to be working.

```
   void setContent(XWPFDocument document) {
    List<XWPFParagraph> paragrahsOfClause = document.getParagraphs()
    paragrahsOfClause.forEach { XWPFParagraph paragraph -> {
            if (this.object instanceof CTSdtBlock) {
                CTSdtBlock ctSdtBlock = (CTSdtBlock) this.object
                if (ctSdtBlock.isSetSdtContent()) {
                    CTSdtContentBlock sdtContentBlock = ctSdtBlock.getSdtContent()
                    sdtContentBlock.PList.add(paragraph.getCTP())
                }
            } else if (this.object instanceof CTSdtRun) {
                CTSdtRun ctSdtRun = (CTSdtRun) this.object
                if (ctSdtRun.isSetSdtContent()) {
                    CTSdtContentRun sdtContentRun = ctSdtRun.getSdtContent()
                    CTR[] ctRArray = paragraph.getCTP().getRArray()
                    sdtContentRun.setRArray(ctRArray)
                }
            } else if (this.object instanceof CTSdtCell) {
                CTSdtCell ctSdtCell = (CTSdtCell) this.object
                if (ctSdtCell.isSetSdtContent()) {
                    CTSdtContentCell sdtContentCell = ctSdtCell.getSdtContent()
                    for (int c = 0; c < sdtContentCell.getTcList().size(); c++) {
                        CTTc ctTc = sdtContentCell.getTcList().get(c)
                        ctTc.PList.add(paragraph.getCTP())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it is being called via this code. Note the other Word Document I am inserting I have as a byte[]

```
    XWPFDocument doc = null
    try {
        
        doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(
                   new ByteArrayInputStream(otherDocFile.fileData)))

    } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage(), e)
    } catch (InvalidOperationException invalidFile) {
        invalidFile.printStackTrace()
    }

     contentControl.setContent(doc)
```